# Opening a file on onedrive through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying to open a file on onedrive through VBA and it opens as doc.aspx instead of the actual file. Im using this code:

```
Sub open_excel_from_one_drive()

sfilename = "sharepoint adress"
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
Set xlsheet = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sfilename, ReadOnly:=True)

End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest a solution or any workarounds? Thank you in advance

Comment: Add a `.` to the end of the filename to indicate that not a default extension should be assumed.

Comment: Well it worked, but now I get a run-time error on line 5. It says, that it cant get the Open feature from the class workbooks.